# Page redirect with path using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I redirect a request with Javascript with path?

```
my-domain.com/abc to www.other-domain.com/abc
```

Where 'abc' would be the request path. Also it is possible to also forward query parameters and fragment identifiers?

Comment: Shouldn't this be done at the server level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be done server-side but if you want to do it with javascript, you can do

`location.href = location.href.replace(/(https?:\/\/)[^/]+/,'$1'+'www.other-domain.com');`

note: that regex includes forwarding with the same protocol as the url.. if you do not include the protocol, it will attempt to redirect to the same domain as the page, but with 'www.other-domain.com/..' as the relative path.  So you must include the protocol. As an alternative, you can just hardcode it like so:

`location.href = location.href.replace(/(https?:\/\/)[^/]+/,'http://www.other-domain.com');`

Comment: Yep, or even `location.host = location.host.replace(/\.de/, ".com")` for  
just replacing in the host component. query parameters do get preserved.
But I agree with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077103/page-redirect-with-path-using-javascript#comment29909040_20077103

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var url = "http://www.other-domain.com" + location.path + location.search + location.hash;
location.href = url;
```

For more info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: Should it be `location.href = url`?

Comment: without the protocol it will redirect to a relative url

Comment: Well I think @xybrek should be able to handle it from here. No need to spell it out any further.

Comment: And I agree, it would be more appropriate to handle this server-side, but lets assume that he is limited to using client-only options.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, but it's highly recommended to be done at server level.

```
window.location = 'www.other-domain.com' + (location.pathname + location.search);
```

Comment: `.pathname` doesn't include query string or hash/fragment

Comment: `location.search` only includes the query string, not the hash/fragment; you also need `location.hash` :P

Comment: I can't even find window.*redirect*.
What environment are you in?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.replace("http://www.other-domain.com/abc");
```

See [Window.location - Web API interfaces | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) for more info.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Depending on the situation `window.location.replace` can be better than setting `window.location.href`.

Comment: i didn't downvote but i imagine it is because you just showed replacing it with a hardcoded value, without passing on the current path, query or hash strings

Comment: Ok. I just used it as an example. The question wasn't very clear IMHO. I just assumed everybody knows how to concatenate a string. Oh well...

Comment: +1 to correct your -1. It is a valid answer to a rather vague question.